# Polymerfire query is not returning new data when path changed

Tags: javascript, firebase, polymer, firebase-realtime-database, polymerfire

Here is [Youtube link](https://youtu.be/CFLbTyoW6bs) for issue

I am trying to change path using firebase-query as following

```
<firebase-query
        id="query"
        log
        order-by-child="name"
        app-name="appname1"
        path="/posts/[[collectionPath]]"
        data="{{posts}}">
</firebase-query>
```

following is my data structure

[image]

```
Polymer({

  is: 'my-view2',

  properties: {
      collectionPath: {
      type: String,
      value: "",
      notify: true
    }
  },
  updatePath:function (selectedTab) {
    this.set('collectionPath', selectedTab);        
  }
});
```

On tab click I am calling function `updatePath()` like `updatePath('Android')`

But query is not returning new data when path changed. It return me data when I reload the app. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i did it myself and i would like to share with you.

Just set path to null i.e **this.$.query.path = null;** as following code

```
updatePath:function (selectedTab) {
  this.$.query.path = null;
  this.set('collectionPath', selectedTab);        
}
```